# Unable to get hidden form value into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with several fields.  The value of one of the hidden fields is passed in the URL along with some other input values like this:

**example.html#firstname=Homer&lastname=Simpson&itype=TARGET**

I have a javascript that parses the URL and that is populating the form just fine. The output of the form contains all of the values passed from the url, so I know the variable are getting passed to the form fields.

My issue is - I want to be able to setup an if statement to change the text of one of the headings based on the value of itype.

Here's my code:

```
        var itypestuff = document.getElementById("itype").value;

        document.write ("<p>The value of the variable is " + itypestuff.value + "</p>");

        if( itypestuff == "TARGET" ){
           document.write("This is the target");
        }

        else{
           document.write("This is not the target");
        }
```

I added the first document.write statement as a debug and it's coming back with: **The value of the variable is undefined**

Here's what the itype field variable looks like:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="itype" id="itype" value="">
```

Any ideas how I can get the variable from the URL into my javascript variable so I can do my if statement?

Comment: Try  `var itypestuff = document.getElementById("itype");` (yes, without the value there)

Comment: Why do you need to read the value from a  hidden field if you are already touching the value in code when you strip it out of the url? Place it in a variable at that moment and then use it later in your processing of the page. This way you would totally skip messing with the DOM.

Comment: My code for stripping it out of the URL and assigning it to form variables is just a loop so it doesn't look at particular variables - it just separates them all and overwrites the empty values for the visible and hidden fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change** :

```
 document.write ("<p>The value of the variable is " + itypestuff.value + "</p>");
```

**To**

```
document.write ("<p>The value of the variable is " + itypestuff + "</p>");
```

### OR

**Change**

```
var itypestuff = document.getElementById("itype").value;
```

**To**

```
var itypestuff = document.getElementById("itype");
// And 
if( itypestuff.value == "TARGET" ){ //...
```

### EDIT

You have to change your html like that :

```
<input type="hidden" name="itype" id="itype" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['itype']); ?>">
```

And call : example.php?firstname=Homer&lastname=Simpson&itype=TARGET

Comment: When I make either of those changes - the document.write statement comes back with a blank (ie The value of the variable is  (nothing here))

Comment: Becauce `value=""` is null. Change by : `value="TARGET"` in your HTML.

Comment: The problem is - I want to pass the value of that form variable from the URL - so it will be TARGET sometimes - but will be MISSEDTARGET other times - I want it to be dynamic and not fixed.  LIke I said - the output when I submit the form of itype is showing TARGET - but it's like it's not getting set in the timeline when the javascript is interrogating the form value.

Comment: Look my edits. I've added what you missing in your html.

Comment: When I do the PHP code - I get: The value of the variable is [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Have you change `"<p>The value of the variable is " + itypestuff.value + "</p>"` by `"<p>The value of the variable is " + itypestuff + "</p>"` ? if yes add the .value., if not try a console.log of itypestuff .value and put here

Comment: I had <?php instead of <?= in the hidden field definition - once I changed it to <?=  it worked!!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: Perfect ! I think you forgot echo with <?php . Because <?= set echo automatically.